ACF Select a repeater row
I have set up a repeater to use as a product thumbnail UI/slider with thumbnails.
The product comes in 2 sizes and I need the slider to change depending on the product size selected by a user drop select.
Is there a way to have a drop select change which repeater row is shown?
An alternate I tried was having multiple sliders load and use jQuery to assign an 'active' class to the slider I needed, but it results in the page loading too much unused content.

Do you mean on the frontend or backend? Please provide a [mcve] when asking a question. Maybe try the plugin support forum: https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/advanced-custom-fields/

@admcfajn that's a good question. I think the solution would need to be backend. I unfortunately don't have a minimal reproducible example as the layout in ACF is what is messing me up.
I guess the easiest way to see what I am trying to do is here https://bloomnu.com/products/greens-superfoods
When you click 30ct, 60ct or 25ct for serving size it changes the thumbnails and large image.
